# form.validateFields() doesnt work when we have custom antd form component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, validation, antd

Considering the following example, this is stopping us to create custom components inside forms using antd4 version.

```
const handleFormSubmit = () => {
  form
    .validateFields()
    .then((values: any) => {
      console.log('success values => ', JSON.stringify(values));
      successCallback(values);
    })
    .catch((errorInfo: any) => {
      console.log('failureCallback values => ', JSON.stringify(errorInfo));
      failureCallback(errorInfo);
    });
};


<Form
  form={form}
  layout="vertical"
  name="normal_login"
  className="login-form"
  initialValues={store.formData.initialValues}
>
  <Form.Item>
    <Input placeholder="Name" />
  </Form.Item>

  <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" onClick={handleFormSubmit}>
    Create
  </Button>
</Form>
```

This works absolutely fine, whereas if the component is custom, then it doesn't work. Example:

```
function CustomInput(props){
  return (
    <Form.Item>
      <Input placeholder={props.name} />
    </Form.Item>
  )
}

<Form
  form={form}
  layout="vertical"
  name="normal_login"
  className="login-form"
  initialValues={store.formData.initialValues}
>

  <CustomInput name="Name" />
```

Will display the field and also validates on change event. HandleFormSubmit is called, but it's not triggering success or failure block.

```
  <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" onClick={handleFormSubmit}>
    Create
  </Button>
</Form>
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: you missing to pass the name to form.

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with antd, but according to the [documentation for customized fields](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-customized-form-controls), it seems that the value of the field should live inside the custom component, not be passed as a prop. Also, they mention a few constraints that must be satisfied in order to have the custom field work correctly. Maybe the example on their website can serve as a guide to adjusting the implementation?

Comment: @sushildlh - here when posting i might have missed to place name, but its there in the actual implementation. Custom components are not working in antd. I want to understand why is it so, whats the actual procedure to use this

Comment: This is a smiple input field which is not working, but what about select, multi select? uff some small example here can help a layman like me in antd start

Comment: for Select and multi select you have to go through the link @LauroMüller provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead of your Custom JSX

```
function CustomInput(props){
  return (
    <Form.Item name={props.name}>  # Update this line only and remove this comment #
      <Input placeholder={props.name} />
    </Form.Item>
  )
}

<Form
  form={form}
  layout="vertical"
  name="normal_login"
  className="login-form"
  initialValues={store.formData.initialValues}
>

  <CustomInput name="Name" /> 

<Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" onClick={handleFormSubmit}>
    Create
  </Button>
</Form>
```

> NOTE: In Antd if your using Form.Item then you have to set name there
> not on input fields. Form.Item assign its value to its Input.

I hope your doubt is solved comment for more views. I also tired of antd and wasted many days to understand this.